# Closing NodeMCU sockets

Tags: sockets, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have recently been playing with  [Adafruit's ESP8266 breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2471). I am hoping to make a simple web server, so I can access/change values over wifi (or beyond!). There is very little documentation I can find, and I have become confused over how to use the `net.socket` objects.

All of the examples I can find have the sockets being closed as soon as the immediate communication is done. For example, from the NodeMCU docs:

```
sv = net.createServer(net.TCP, 30)

function receiver(sck, data)
  print(data)
  sck:close()
end

if sv then
  sv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", receiver)
    conn:send("hello world")
  end)
end
```

Here a new socket is created, the response is sent, then the socket is closed. However, my understanding of a socket is that the connection exists until the server or the client explicitly closes it... So shouldn't the socket stay open?

Thank you for all info / advice.

EDIT:
Although i didn't get any clear answer, the webserver library Marcel recommended is great! I was able to model my implementation off of this one.

Comment: I wouldn't write a server from scratch but use https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver instead - except for the learning experience of course.

Comment: If you couldn't close a socket until the other end of the connection had already closed the socket - it would be impossible to ever close a socket.